# Listing all ancestor paths, LIKE vs rcte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, recursive-query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;

CREATE TABLE t(
    mypath varchar(100),
    parent_path varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('a', NULL),('a/b', 'a'),('a/b/c', 'a/b');
```

-- Listing all parent paths

1) using LIKE, not making use of parent_path column:

```
SELECT a.mypath, b.mypath aS parent_path
FROM t a
JOIN t b ON a.mypath LIKE b.mypath + '%' AND a.mypath != b.mypath
```

[image]

2) Using a recursive cte, making use of parent_path column

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT mypath, parent_path
    FROM t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.mypath, b.parent_path
    FROM cte a
    JOIN t b ON a.parent_path = b.mypath
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE parent_path IS NOT NULL;
```

[image]

On large datasets, what are the pros and cons of each method, performance wise ?
Am I right to thing the rcte method should be faster ?
Should LIKE be able to make use of an index, since there is only a trailing wildcard ?

Comment: I tend to use Range Keys.  Once established, they make it super easy for navigation and/or aggregation   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43127166/efficient-way-to-get-ancestors-materialized-path/43128196#43128196

Comment: Is this data overly simplified? If not, would a `hierarchyid` not be a better suite here?

Comment: You mean a FK to an int PK ? Could be a good idea, yes.

Comment: You can test this yourself easily and examine the execution plans on your real data using your real queries. Performance questions are almost always highly specific to the schema, query, and data.